# Use Script RTTI in DWSWebServer

Tags: delphi, rtti, dwscript

At the moment I'm playing a little bit with the DWSWebServer. I really like the idea of coding dynamic websites with a pascal style language. 
Now I would like to implement a simple ORM using the script-side-RTTI. But the scriptcompiler does not know any RTTI functions or classes.

E.g. if I try the following code:

```
var test := RTTIRawAttributes;
```

I will get:

```
Syntax Error: Unknown name "RTTIRawAttributes" [line: 16, column: 14]
```

I have already successfully compiled the latest version of the webserver, so is some option needed or library missing for RTTI support?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddenly I got the answer on my own. I had to include the "dwsRTTIFunctions.pas" Unit and recompile the server. Now it works and I can use the RTTI inside my webscripts :)